# Automate cropping with Pillow and python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

So I have a folder with 500+ images that need to be cropped. And I have searched and have manage to create this cut-and-paste script. But, for some reason it doesn't save the new image!? The terminal is just still, no errors no nothing.

```
from PIL import Image # import the Python Image processing Library
import os # To read the folder

directory_in_str = "/Users/hora/Downloads/Etik"
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

for file in os.listdir(directory):
     filename = os.fsdecode(file)
     if filename.endswith(".png"):
        image = os.path.join(directory_in_str, filename)
        imageObject  = Image.open(image) # Create an Image object from an Image
        cropped     = imageObject.crop((1025,85,2340,2040)) # Crop the iceberg portion (top left x, top left y, bottom right x, bottom right y)
        cropped.save("{}".format(filename+"_cropped"), 'png') # Save the cropped portion
        continue
     else:
        continue
```

Im searching in a specific folder, and the cropped image should be saved with a `filename_cropped.png`. But not necessary, I have backups if something should go side-ways.

### The expected result:

- Loop through a folder
- Crop all images ending with `.png`
- And save the crop image with the previous filename but with extension
  `FILNAME_cropped.png`
- Done

Comment: You don't actually need to write any Python for this, you can do it very simply with an **ImageMagick** one-liner if that's an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues regarding this line:

```py
cropped.save("{}".format(filename+"_cropped"), 'png')
```

1. Your `filename` still contains the file extension.
2. You don't add a (new) file extension yourself.

Both issues result in some string `xxx.png_cropped` for your new file.

My suggestion to modify your code:

```py
for file in os.listdir(directory):
     filename = os.fsdecode(file)
     if filename.endswith(".png"):
        image = os.path.join(directory_in_str, filename)
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)       # <-- After reading, filename can be overwritten
        imageObject = Image.open(image)
        cropped = imageObject.crop((1025,85,2340,2040))
        cropped.save("{}".format(filename+"_cropped.png"), 'png')   # <-- Explicitly add .png to your filename 
        continue
     else:
        continue
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

add the directory path in saving the file.

```
directory_in_str = "/Users/hora/Downloads/Etik/"
cropped.save("{}".format(directory_in_str+filename+"_cropped"),'png')
```